# Flutter using plugins inside flutter workmanager plugin callbackDispatcher function

Tags: flutter

I try to use sqflite plugin inside background process with flutter workmanager. I have an SQLHelper class which for sqflite operations. I can use this helper inside application. But in this background process, it gives error as below

Exception has occurred:

```
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getDatabasesPath on channel com.tekartik.sqflite))
```

Probably I have to register plugin inside callbackDispatcher, but I'm not sure. How can I solve this problem?

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
    Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {

        SQLHelper db = SQLHelper();
        ServerSetting sItem = await db.settingGetItem();
        print(sItem.hidetriggermaintenance);    
        return Future.value(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Found a solution? I am facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to register sqflite plugin on native side, as stated here: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/troubleshooting.md